# Structure of QGIS_Processing commands

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

As per https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/standalone.html?highlight=qgis_process I am trying to run the following (that works in the QGIS python console).

```
alg_params = {
           'EXPRESSION': '"Speed KmH"  < '+ str(max_speed) ,
            'INPUT': in_file,
            'OUTPUT': 'd:/scratch/1.tab',
            }               

outputs['ExtractByExpression']=processing.run('native:extractbyexpression', alg_params)
```

When I run the following in OSGEO Shell I get

> ```
> C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin>qgis_process run qgis:extractbyexpression -- INPUT=d:\scratch\1.csv OUTPUT=D:\scratch\1.tab EXPRESSION="FID"<30
> ```
>
> C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin>qgis_process run qgis:extractbyexpression --
> INPUT=d:\scratch\1.csv OUTPUT=D:\scratch\1.tab    Traceback (most
> recent call last):
> Problem with OTB installation: OTB folder is not set.
> ----------------                                                                                                        Inputs
> ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                INPUT:  d:\scratch\1.csv
> OUTPUT: D:\scratch\1.tab
> ERROR: The following mandatory parameters were not specified
> EXPRESSION:     Expression
> C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin>

How do I structure the expression? I have tried it in single quotes and double quotes. It accepts the input/output when we use = rather than : but I just can't get even a simple expression to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to wrap the expression in double quotes, because the `<` character is a reserved character within the windows command line used for redirecting inputs/outputs.

The following command works for me using QGIS 3.22:

```
qgis_process-qgis-ltr run qgis:extractbyexpression -- INPUT=D:\Downloads\1.shp OUTPUT=D:\Downloads\1.tab EXPRESSION=""FID"<30"
```

```
> ----------------
> Inputs
> ----------------

> EXPRESSION:     FID<30
> INPUT:  D:\Downloads\1.shp
> OUTPUT: D:\Downloads\1.tab
>
>
> Warning 6: driver MapInfo File does not support creation option BLOCK_SIZE
> 0...10..
> ----------------
> Results
> ----------------
>
> OUTPUT: D:\Downloads\1.tab
```

Some additional notes:

- my command uses `qgis_process-qgis-ltr` because I ran on the standalone version of QGIS. With your installation through OSGeo keep using `qgis_process`
- if the file paths of input or output contain any spaces (or reserved characters such as & , | , ( , ) , < , > , ^), you also need to wrap the path with double quotes e.g. `INPUT="D:\Test Data\1.shp"`